# How to create a simple WCF service with a TCP/IP duplex connection?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm trying to learn how to create a web service that is capable of both sending and receiving data.
As an example I have defined a ServerTimeService:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ServerTimeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    DateTime GetServerTime();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    DateTime SendServerTime();
}
```

Now I am told I should be providing a callback contract, but I really don't get why or what it is? When is the callback contract called?
Further more I'd like to see a code exmple sending the server time and receiving it at the client.

Comment: Callback is a way to call a method from the client to the server in **Duplex** service.

Comment: @Maxim: What if I want the server to call a method in the client?

Answer (score 7):

Here's another simple duplex example that outlines the basics pretty well. An example project is included.
http://realfiction.net/2008/01/30/the-no-frills-bare-bones-example-to-duplex-wcf

Comment: I'm using this example and it's so simple it's amazing